# How to get individual fields in embedded documents?

Tags: mongodb

Lets say i have a document like following

```
{
"_id" : 1,
"name" : "sue",
"age" : 19,
"type" : 1,
"status" : "P",
"favorites" : {
    "artist" : "Picasso",
    "food" : "pizza"
},
"finished" : [
    17,
    3
],
"badges" : [
    "blue",
    "black"
],
"points" : [
    {
        "points" : 85,
        "bonus" : 20
    },
    {
        "points" : 85,
        "bonus" : 10
    }
]
```

}

when i run query like `db.users.find( { favorites: { artist: "Picasso", food: "pizza" } }, { "favorites.food": 1  } ).pretty()`

i am getting following result

```
{ "_id" : 1, "favorites" : { "food" : "pizza" } }
```

Is it possible to get only `food` field like

> { "food" : "pizza" }

without `favorites` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this using aggregation with **`$project`**

```
db.users.aggregate([  
   {  
      $match:{  
         favorites:{  
            artist:"Picasso",
            food:"pizza"
         }
      }
   },
   {  
      $project:{  
         _id:0,
         food:"$favorites.food"
      }
   }
])
```

Comment: i am getting empty document like `{ }`

Comment: thanks man, can u please tell me diffference between `aggregate` and `find` if possible

Comment: @N.HariHaraSudhan aggregation is similar to find() but it allows you to achive more complex queries/document reformatting; See [aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) for details

Comment: according to your answer i am assuming it takes `$favorites` variable reference  for object `favorites`  , then it add `food : $favorites.food` as a new field in document, am i right??