# Mongoose populate data key remove in got data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I'm using relation between two collection and I have collection schema like follow.

```
// Room database Entry.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d927"),
    "room_id" : "c3wqqkfndg9cnmi",
    "room_name" : "bcmvnxbcnvsjkfhkjdh",
    "users" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d926")
        }
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}

//User Database Entry, Related with above Room entry.
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d926"),
    "user_id" : "dyr1qlrtso47vi",

    "__v" : 0
}
```

When I pass query for Room Find and populate the data than I found result like follow.

```
// Query For Room find and Populate.
room
 .findOne({ room_id: result.data.room_id })
 .populate("users._id")
 .exec(function(err, data){
  });

//Result As Follow
{
   "_id":"59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d927",
   "room_id":"c3wqqkfndg9cnmi",
   "room_name":"bcmvnxbcnvsjkfhkjdh",
   "__v":0,
   "users":[
      {
         "_id":{
            "_id":"59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d926",
            "user_id":"dyr1qlrtso47vi",
            "__v":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

My Requirement is like follow, I don't want `_id` as key of object. I need `users` object like follow.

```
"users":[
      {
         "_id":{
            "_id":"59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d926",
            "user_id":"dyr1qlrtso47vi",
            "__v":0
         }
      }
   ]

Should be 

"users":[
         {
            "_id":"59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d926",
            "user_id":"dyr1qlrtso47vi",
            "__v":0
         }
     ]
```

Comment: try to use [project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43650014/how-to-get-individual-fields-in-embedded-documents/43650072#43650072)

Comment: Buddy I'm using populate for relation between two collection.

Comment: Nonetheless you really should be using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) where available and also understanding "why" you should be using it instead. Populate is nowhere near the same thing. Whilst you could alter the document structure once returned, the real problem here is your structure was incorrect to begin with. The room data should have the `users` array as `"users" : [ObjectId("59b77082f7da4b1b3f64d926")]`. And to do that the schema should instead be `"users": [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]`. The inner `_id` is a mistake